# Name for presenting two arguments and letting the reader make their own decision?

Tags: single-word-requests, vocabulary

As the title says, is there word for presenting two arguments and letting the reader draw their own conclusions from that? For example, let's say that someone has asked for my thoughts on restaurants A and B. If I said that A was good for a, b, and c, and B was good because of d, e, and f, then let the person asking make their own decision. Is there even a name for this? I feel like it's on the tip of my tongue, but I just can't think of what it's called.

Thanks

Comment: is the repeated 'c' argument a feature, or do you mean 'd, e and f'?

Comment: @JonMarkPerry Oops, I'll fix that now.

Comment: You're presenting a _balanced argument_. But I'd just go with 'weighing up the pro's and cons' in this conversational register. Once I'd checked to see if pro's is one of those extremely rare plurals that can be formed using an apostrophe.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Yeah, it seems like that's what I'm going to have to call it. Thanks!

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth: Why would you think  pros might have an apostrophe when cons doesn't?  Does it just "look wrong" without it?  Like "dos and dont's"

Comment: There are several pure plurals that accepted apostrophised spellings exist for. I know that do's and ex's are two; I'd agree that pros looks garden-pathy at the very least. According to one style suggested by Lynne Truss, any word[-used]-as-a-word is italicised and given an 's in the plural (thus _Truss_'s).

Comment: Are you looking for "dilemma" ? for example:  *Would you rather* is a party game; the idea is to present a dilemma in the form of a question that has two options.

Comment: Doesn't sound like an argument or two arguments to me. Sounds like a statement followed by reasons for it from a) to f). Sounds like mix-and-match for coming up with a mixed-bag of reasons, some of which are acceptable to one group of people and others of which are acceptable to others.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some single word choices for presenting two choices equally: *unbiased, impartial, nonpartisan, neutral.*

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably use something like "I gave him the full skinny on either" here.

From WordNet (r) 3.0 (2006) [wn]:

> skinny
> n 1: confidential information about a topic or person; "he
>            wanted the inside skinny on the new partner"